# Date filter using sapui5

Tags: javascript, date, sapui5

I want to use filter with date , the  filter should be somthing like that :

```
/MyEntitySet?$filter=Erdat gt datetime'2018-02-04T00:00:00' and Erdat lt 
datetime'2018-02-04T00:00:00
```

But I don't get that while using this in sapui5 :

```js
var date = this.byId("date1").getDateValue();
var date2 = this.byId("date2").getValue();
var oDateFormat = sap.ui.core.format.DateFormat.getInstance({
  pattern: "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss"
});
var oDate = oDateFormat.format(oDateFormat.parse(date));

var oDateFormat2 = sap.ui.core.format.DateFormat.getInstance({
  pattern: 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:MM:SS'
});
var oDate2 = oDateFormat.format(oDateFormat.parse(date2));
```

Anyone have an idea about that please , I will be grateful. Thank you

Comment: What is the service expecting ( which type)? Which oData Version do you use? Which error does occur?

Comment: i'm still a biginner in sap . but the service expect :
/MyEntitySet?$filter=Erdat gt datetime'2018-02-04T00:00:00' and Erdat lt 
datetime'2018-02-04T00:00:00 
 when i try this url it works it get data from my table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to format the data by yourself, just build the Filter and apply to the odata request directly.

```
sap.ui.define(['sap/ui/model/Filter', 'sap/ui/model/FilterOperator'], 
  function(Filter, FilterOperator) {
    new Filter({
      path: "Erdat",
      operator: FilterOperator.BT,
      value1: date,
      value2: date2
    });
  });
```